# Creating a function to grab data from an Oracle database (array by ID)

Tags: php, oracle, select, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to create a function that will simply allow me to pass an SQL statement into it, and it will generate an array based on a unique ID I pass it:

```
function oracleGetGata($query, $id="id") {
    global $conn;
    $sql = OCI_Parse($conn, $query);
    OCI_Execute($sql);
    OCI_Fetch_All($sql, $results, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);
    return $results;
}
```

For example I'd like this query `$array = oracleGetData('select * from table')` to return something like:

```
[1] => Array
(
    [Title] => Title 1
    [Description] => Description 1
)
[2] => Array
(
    [Title] => Title 2
    [Description] => Description 2
)
[3] => Array
(
    [Title] => Title 3
    [Description] => Description 3
)
```

Rather than what it's returning at the moment:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [ID] => 3
    [TITLE] => Title 3
    [DESCRIPTION] => Description 3
)
[1] => Array
(
    [ID] => 1
    [TITLE] => Title 1
    [DESCRIPTION] => Description 1
)
[2] => Array
(
    [ID] => 2
    [TITLE] => Title 2
    [DESCRIPTION] => Description 2
)
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this, as the function would save me *lots* of time! Thank you.

Comment: I didn't get the `$id='id'` part of the question but acording the the documentation at http://docs.php.net/OCI_Fetch_All the `flags` parameter is the fifth paramenter not the fourth as as in your example.

Comment: Ah! Many thanks for the response, it works as the fifth paramter :) I was wondering if I could pass the name of the 'ID' column though so it populates the array via that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested and without proper error handling:

```
function oracleGetGata($query, $id="id") {
    global $conn;

    $results = array();
    $sql = OCI_Parse($conn, $query);
    OCI_Execute($sql);
    while ( false!==($row=oci_fetch_assoc($sql)) ) {
        $results[ $row[$id] ] = $row;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! thank you so much, I'll add in a sort and some error handling now :-) Thank you!!!!