# Function for querying Oracle database - 'Undefined index' notice

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, select, oracle-call-interface

To give some context, a little while ago with the help from VolkerK on this very site I created a function that queries an Oracle database and places the content into a neatly formatted PHP array, depending on the index. [Here's the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803202/creating-a-function-to-grab-data-from-an-oracle-database-array-by-id).

The problem is, in some cases I just want to return a single value from a quick query, and when I do I get the the following error: `Notice: Undefined index:`

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function oracleGetData($query, $id = null) {
    global $conn;

    $results = array();
    $sql = OCI_Parse($conn, $query);
    OCI_Execute($sql);
    while ( false!==($row=oci_fetch_assoc($sql)) ) {
        $results[ $row[$id] ] = $row;
    }

    // remove one layer if there's only one record
    if(count($results) == 1 and is_null($id)) {
        $results = array_pop($results);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

I have tried changing the line that populates the array like so:

```
if(is_null($id)) {
    while ( false!==($row=oci_fetch_assoc($sql)) ) {
        $results[ $row ] = $row;
    }
} else {
    while ( false!==($row=oci_fetch_assoc($sql)) ) {
        $results[ $row[$id] ] = $row;
    }
}
```

Basically if the $id variable is null, remove all references to it, but then I get a 'Warning: Illegal offset type' error.

Any help would be much appreciated, I've tried passing in the single field I require into the function but get the same error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps if $id is NULL you could just use sequential numbers for the indexes, as in:

```
function oracleGetData($query, $id = null)
  { 
  global $conn; 

  $results = array(); 
  $sql = OCI_Parse($conn, $query); 
  OCI_Execute($sql); 

  if(is_null($id)) {
    $idx = 1;

    while (false!==($row=oci_fetch_assoc($sql))) { 
      $results[ $idx ] = $row;
      $idx = $idx + 1;
    }
  } else { 
    while ( false!==($row=oci_fetch_assoc($sql))) { 
      $results[ $row[$id] ] = $row;
    }
  } 

  // remove one layer if there's only one record 

  if(count($results) == 1 and is_null($id)) { 
    $results = array_pop($results); 
  } 

  return $results; 
  }
```

Share and enjoy.