# How can I connect to an Oracle database from PHP in response to an onChange event?

Tags: php, oracle

This is code I saw [for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9803877/266304).

```
function oracleGetGata($query, $id="id") {
    global $conn;

    $results = array();
    $sql = OCI_Parse($conn, $query);
    OCI_Execute($sql);
    while ( false!==($row=oci_fetch_assoc($sql)) ) {
        $results[ $row[$id] ] = $row;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

My question is how does this make the connection to Oracle and then call it inside this function? Because I can see `global $conn` but I don't know where that is coming from.

My problem is that I have an `onChange` function on an input box. When the value is changed it needs to call a function which connects to Oracle and checks if value is valid, and echo `VALID` if it is.

Comment: So make an Ajax call and call your PHP file with the data.

Comment: That's just PHP, there's no Javascript in it at all. `$conn` is a global variable that was set elsewhere in the script (possibly in an include file that connects to the database).

Answer (score 0):

The `global $conn;` imports into oracleGetGata() a global variable named $conn which is almost certainly the database connection, created somewhere outside the scope of the function.